# Invalid entries in $PATH after upgrading to macOS Ventura 13.3 [com.apple.security.cryptexd]

Tags: terminal, path, ventura

After upgrading to macOS Ventura 13.3, when I open **Terminal** app, I notice these 3 entries in my `$PATH` variable that were non-existent directories:

```
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
```

(All other entries in `$PATH` were fine, btw)

On the first look, it appears that **Terminal** is expecting `/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap` to be some sort of a mounted directory. But when I check, it is just an empty directory:

```
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap % ls -l
total 0
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap %
```

Now, how to fix this issue?

Comment: Which issue needs fixing here?

Comment: @nohillside I don't need invalid entries in my `$PATH` variable. I have a script that runs every time I open a new shell to check for invalid entries in `$PATH` and throws error. Having only valid paths in `$PATH` is a useful to me in several ways. Which is why, I don't want to ignore this issue.

Answer (score 10):

Cryptexes are used to update parts of macOS quickly, without requiring a full rebuild of the SSV (see https://eclecticlight.co/2023/04/05/how-cryptexes-are-changing-macos-ventura/ for details).

I don't know whether removing these paths will break the installation of such cryptexes. But if you want to take the risk, you can remove `/etc/paths.d/10-cryptex` (or move it to a safe place in case you need it later on).

PS: Invalid entries in PATH don't really hurt, they primarily slow down (a very little bit) the lookup of new commands run from the shell the first time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and timely reference to Howard's blog. I found these in my PATH too. Perhaps this indicates something failed in the macOS 13.3.1 update, or someone removed some cleanup scripts by mistake.

Comment: I think you can remove it safely because you'll find now: `/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin` in the PATH, which is actually existing.

Comment: @ralfzen And where does this PATH entry come from? Would assume from the file I mentioned in the answer?

Comment: @nohillside No in the mentioned file I find only those entries:
`/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin`

So it must come from somewhere else, but I could not find out from where.

Comment: @ralfzen The whole thing probably is still  partially work-in-progress by Apple. IMHO it's just a bad idea to remove these paths in general, they don't hurt.