# Remove unwanted entries in $PATH

Tags: terminal, iterm, zsh, path

I have multiple entries in my `$PATH`. I learned a ton about the path environment variable yesterday, but prior that I must have added some entries multiple time, or something.

I have searched for this entry in the following files, with no success:

```
/home/.zshrc no .zprofile in home
/etc/zshrc
/etc/zprofile
/etc/zsh_Apple_Terminal
/etc/paths
/etc/path.d
```

I'm using Oh-My-Zsh, with iTerm2. I know, that this Path is probably harmless, but i am curious where does this come from?

```
echo $path /usr/local/bin /System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin

cat /etc/paths /usr/local/bin /System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
```

Comment: What about the `.zshrc` and/or `.zprofile` in your HOME directory?  When you say “without success,” what does that mean exactly?  What did/didn’t you find?

Comment: Does the third line contain one entry of PATH  or four?

Comment: @nohillside that is 4 entries

Comment: @Allan I've searched in these files, but there is no such entry like /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap. I have these in /etc/paths: /usr/local/bin
/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin
/usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin 
I don't know where the others come from.

Comment: And the first part of my question?  Please post clarifications to the comment(s) with an [edit]

Comment: I don't see any duplicates.  Just 3 entries over 6 lines instead of 3.  They should look like this: /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin Don't you see any colons?

Comment: Please run `echo $PATH` and add the result to the question without any editing.

Comment: I don't see any duplicate entries in that list.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458277/invalid-entries-in-path-after-upgrading-to-macos-ventura-13-3-com-apple-securi

Comment: @nohillside thanks a lot for the link, it solved my issue!

Comment: Do a `typeset -aU path` in one of your startup-files (for instance `~/.zshrc`), and the shell will take care itself of removing duplicates. The first occurance will be kept, the later ones disappear.